# Simplepie, how to get the url feed inserted

Tags: php, simplepie

I am using this plugin for my website and I am struggling with problem I have. I use a multifeed system and the code looks like this :

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url($feedsArray);
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();
$feed->set_item_limit(50);

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item){

     $data[] = array( 'title' => $item->get_title(), 'description' => $item->get_description() );

}
```

Everything works perfectly but, what I want is to introduce in the $data array a value like "feedUrl" which is the url used in $feedsArray for the actual item. Remember this array contains all the urls and I want the url used for the actual item where I get news.

Sorry if my explanation is a bit confusing,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Use `$feed->get_permalink();` for the feed's link or `$item->get_permalink();` for the item's permalink.</del>

**Update**

Use `'feedUrl' =>  $item->get_base('href')`:

```
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {

     $data[] = array( 'feedUrl' =>  $item->get_base('href'), 'title' => $item->get_title(), 'description' => $item->get_description() );

}
```

Comment: That's not what I want. It returns the URL of the item but now the "SOURCE". I mean, what I want is to get the feed url, not the url of the item. Do you understand what I mean ?

Comment: Try with `$item->get_base('href');`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full URL that you entered originally, use:

```
$item->get_feed()->subscribe_url()
```

http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/subscribe_url